# GET Body - Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http

I am implementing a login method. When the user logs in, the backend generates a JWT and sends the token to be stored in the localStorage of the HTML. I have never used the TS / Angular 4, in AngularJS I had no problem with that, see my function, told me it is not working?

```
  login(){
    this.auth.authenticate(this.creds)
      .subscribe(response => {
        console.log("response: ", response.body.token)
        this.auth.successfulLogin(response.headers.get('Authorization'))
        this.navCtrl.setRoot('DetalhesViagemPage')
      },
      error => {})
  }
```

Return from `console.log("response: ", response.body)`

```
response:  {"nome":"Frederico","_id":"5b21a4332a5e3333cc64a12f","token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyIkX18iOnsic3RyaWN0TW9kZSI6dHJ1ZSwic2VsZWN0"}
```

I have amended my question to make it clearer.

Comment: Are you asking how to access the `name` property..? That would just be `response.body.name`...

Comment: you question is very unclear

Comment: see the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to get the name property, you just have to access to it like this:

```
response.body.name
```

Just use the properties like you get the body property.